# C++ clr снять mini damp с запущенного C# кода

Tags: c#, c++, clr, dump

Как идеологически правильно снять мини дамп с запущенного из C++ (clr hosting) C# кода при возникновении исключения?

На мой взгляд проблема состоит в том что при исключении завершается процесс `AppDomain->Load3(..)` в процессе которого и крутится C# код.

Как правильно это организовать? Использовать дополнительный интерфейс IDebug итд?

Дамп есть желание снимать `MiniDumpWriteDump()`, возможно это не правильный выбор, при этом снимать хочется именно **мини дамп**, полный дамп слишком велик для задачи.

Comment: Если интересует только crush dump, то для этого вроде WER можно использовать.

Comment: Тут вопрос в том в какой момент и как добраться до блока C# кода в памяти, вот это самый тонкий момент, как это сделать с WER не очень понимаю, если можно пример.

Comment: @LLENN, на самом деле, приложение 'лоадер' это чисто `C++` приложение взаимодействующее с `CLR` по  `COM` интерфейсу, `cli` как и флага `/clr` при сборке там нет :) https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0

Comment: Может вот это: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps , или вам нужно снять именно до того, как доходит до аварийного завершения процесса?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, спасибо за ссылку, но там вроде написано `..включая приложения .NET, не поддерживаются этой функцией`

Comment: Эта надпись вводит в заблуждение. На самом деле не поддерживаются только .NET приложения со своей системой обработки ошибок (например WinForms с параметрами по умолчанию не доводит до аварийного завершения процесса, а выводит свое сообщение об ошибке). Но в общем случае, дампы могут формироваться и для .NET приложений. Для обычного консольного приложения это работает.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, спасибо за разъяснения, да, действительно :) но написано так что при беглом чтении возникает ощущение от прочитанного что не поддерживает..